# How to prevent Aws Step Function from inserting the parent key "Input" when it invokes a Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

How can I define an AWS Step Function state that passes precisely the same hash into an invoked Lambda that I supplied to the Step Function (e.g., without pushing the input hash down one level under a new key "Input")?

My ruby AWS Lambda Function assumes the incoming `event` hash looks like:

```
{
  "queryStringParameters": {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

When I perform a test execution on an AWS Step Function, which invokes that lambda, and supply that same hash shown above, the `event` hash that gets passed into the lambda is not the same as the hash I provided to the Step Function... it has an *extra* parent key called "Input":

```
{
  "Input": 
   {
     "queryStringParameters": {
        "foo": "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

In the Step Function, the state which invokes the lambda is defined by:

```
    "invoke foobar": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:xxxx:xxxx:function:xxxx:$LATEST",
        "Payload": {
          "Input.$": "$"
        }
      },
      "Next": "Done",
      "TimeoutSeconds": 10
    },
```

Or will a Step Function *always* take its input and put it "under" a key called "Input"?

And if that is the case that an "Input" key is always added to the event hash passed to a Lambda function, how does one write a Lambda so it can be invoked from *both* a Step Function (which assumes a root key of "Input") and an API Gateway (which uses a different root key "queryStringParameters")?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
"Payload": {
  "Input.$": "$"
}
```

you should do this:

```
"Payload.$": "$"
```

That will pass in the input directly to the `Payload` of the lambda function.

Comment: perfect, thanks! still wrapping my head around ASL.